# Android Quiet Notification

Tags: android, notifications

I am creating an app which plays audio in the background. I have created a background service and a persistent notification to indicate that the music is currently playing.

However, when I create the notification it feels to strong (e.g. the same as when a new txt or email comes in.) and slides down in the status bar. Instead, I would like the notification to just appear in the status bar without anything fancy. I see other apps which do this, but I cannot figure out how it is done.

I have experimented with different notification flags, but I haven't found one that works. I also don't see anything in the NotificationManager which would help.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How do to...what? "without anything fancy" is a rather vague description of what you are seeking.

Comment: Whenever I display a notification through the NotificationManager, The notification text temporarily takes up the entirety of the status bar, after which the icon appears in the tray. Some apps display notifications that go directly to the tray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up just re-using the same instance of the Notification object passed to NotificationManager rather than passing in a new one with the same ID.